# :active selector occurs only on click

Tags: css

With the following HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

And the CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {outline: none; border: thin solid red}
input[type="text"]:active {border: thin solid yellow}
```

I hoped that the text field would have a yellow border when it is active (when the user is typing). However, the new style only applies when you are clicking on the element. How can I reach the effect I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `:focus`:

```
input[type="text"]:focus {border: thin solid yellow}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anL17tu9/).

---

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act):

> The `:active` pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.
>
> The `:focus` pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus (accepts keyboard or mouse events, or other forms of input).